# dart sass compile file and resolve imports

Tags: sass, dart-sass

I'am working with **sass** progmatically, So I want to compile a scss file.

```
const sourcePath = '******/******/****';
const code = sass.compile(sourcePath).css.toString();
```

I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred:
@import '.\common\index';
@import '.\login2\index';
@import '.\login-sms\index';
: no such file or directory
```

I finnd that there is an option importers compile method:

```
const code = sass.compile(sourcePath, {
    importers: [];
}).css.toString();
```

But, I don't find what to put in importers!

Comment: [See this](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/interfaces/Importer)